# Why does having SNDBUF too low break HTTP?

Tags: http, sockets, networking, tcp

I've got a simple custom HTTP server serving clients.

With SNDBUF set to 512000 everything works fine. However, setting it lower or leaving it at the default (whatever that is) results in Chrome and Firefox not receiving all of the response data – Firefox truncates it after around 150000 - 250000 bytes (the offset changes every time, even though the content stays the same), and Chrome gives an error with no details.

The particular response at issue is about 300000 bytes, and sent all in one chunk.

Tools like [Rex Swain's HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html), curl and wget report no such problem, and show all of the data.

Why does setting the SNDBUF affect Chrome and Firefox's ability to receive the data? I understand how SNDBUF impacts performance, but I don't understand how setting it too low could corrupt a stream?

Comment: Custom HTTP server ... audit all your `write(2)`/`writev(2)`/`send(2)` calls to see if they handle return values properly. That seems the most likely source of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Amount of data you can write into underlying socket at a time is limited by the send buffer size available at the time. As Nikolai said, you will need to check return value from send(), or equivalent, to find out if all data you passed in the function has been written to the send buffer. If not, then you will need to wait for the socket to become 'writable' again, then write the outstanding data.

There are a number of reasons why point of truncation differs between different browsers/HTTP clients. One reason could be the receiver's (client's) receive buffer size of its socket because the size determines the TCP congestion window size (for flow control) which also affects actual transmission speed. Another possible reason would be that the HTTP Viewer/curl/wget may just be reading socket faster than how Chrome or Firefox reads, etc.